# Is there an equivallent for NSXMLParserDelegate in the cocoa touch framework?

Tags: xml, cocoa-touch, parsing

Like the title says, I want to parse XML in my iPhone application, but there is no `NSXMLParserDelegate` protocol like there is in the System Foundation framework.

Can I just add a reference to the `/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework` in my iPhone application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NSXMLParser documentation shows the delegate methods available to you

Answer (score 0):

Actually its ok, instead of implementing the `NSXMLParserDelegate` you can just not implement it and define the require methods, like:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName  attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
}
```

and it magically works :)

Answer (score 0):

Also, a good library for parsing XML is [TouchXml](http://code.google.com/p/touchcode/wiki/TouchXML). I use it for parsing XML and its pretty easy to work with.